# Keep getting "missing 1 required positional argument" but the argument is given

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a problem with my discord bot. (discord.py)

Here is my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def mute(ctx):
    muteRole = discord.Guild.get_role(845612659940524032)
    if(message.author.kick_members == True):
        return

    else:
        await ctx.send('You don\'t have the permission for that')
```

Everything seems right to me. But when I test the command, I always get this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: get_role() missing 1 required positional argument: 'role_id'
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: My guess is that you are trying to use a non-static method of class Guild and the number you are passing to `get_role` is interpreted as the `self` argument, which would explain your exception. Should you not instantiate from class Guild ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've not quite understood how this works. `discord.Guild` is a class, **not** an instance, of which you're calling the function `get_role()`. Thats where your error comes from. To fix this, use the instance `ctx.guild` instead.

```
muteRole = ctx.guild.get_role(845612659940524032)
```

Also `message.author.kick_members` won't work here. First of all, because `message` isn't defined anywhere, use `ctx.message` instead. Furthermore, `ctx.message.author` does not have the attribute `kick_members`, maybe try using the decorator instead

```
@bot.command()
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def mute(ctx):
    muteRole = ctx.guild.get_role(845612659940524032)
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! but when I try your code I just get another error code: 
NameError: name 'has_permissions' is not defined 
sorry for my questions I am not THAT used to this rewrite thing....

Comment: You will then need to import `from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions`